# Where is the Storm Boomerang located in the books?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, published-adventures, books, princes-of-the-apocalypse

I have seen references to a [Storm Boomerang](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/storm-boomerang) on D&D Beyond and a couple of other places, saying it's in *Princes of the Apocalypse*. I have the book, but cannot find it anywhere. Can someone give me a page number?
Or is this from a non-5e book?

Comment: Hi Darryl, welcome to RPG StackExchange!  You might want to take the [tour].

Answer (score 11):

The item location and description is on p. 82 of the physical book under the heading:

> [A13. Vergadain’s Hall](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/adventures/pota/air-earth-fire-and-water#A13VergadainsHall)

Further description of it is on [p. 223](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/adventures/pota/monsters-and-magic-items#StormBoomerang) (Chapter 7).